CnsoDB restart panic:Condition failed: `rest.is_empty()`
CnsoDB restart panic:Condition failed: `rest.is_empty()`
deploy: singleton
version: 2.4.1, revision 4a1035f5f35e426c27169eb517c213a2aa707c07
I built a cnosdb service, write data through the load_cnosdb tool and query by iot-benchmark.
About five or six days later, I discovered that there were a large number of handle leaks, and subsequently cleaned up the leaked handles.And restart cnosdb, the cnosdb panic:
thread 'main' panicked at /home/runner/work/cnosdb/cnosdb/tskv/src/kvcore.rs:119:18:
called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: IndexErr { source: IndexStorage { msg: "Condition failed: `rest.is_empty()`", location: Location { file: "/home/runner/work/cnosdb/cnosdb/tskv/src/index/engine.rs", line: 35, column: 67 }, backtrace: Backtrace(   0: tskv::version_set::VersionSet::new::{{closure}}
   1: tskv::kvcore::TsKv::open::{{closure}}
   2: cnosdb::server::ServiceBuilder::create_tskv::{{closure}}
   3: cnosdb::server::ServiceBuilder::build_query_storage::{{closure}}
   4: cnosdb::main::{{closure}}
   5: cnosdb::main
   6: std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace
   7: std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}}
   8: core::ops::function::impls::<impl core::ops::function::FnOnce<A> for &F>::call_once
             at rustc/07dca489ac2d933c78d3c5158e3f43beefeb02ce/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:284:13
      std::panicking::try::do_call
             at rustc/07dca489ac2d933c78d3c5158e3f43beefeb02ce/library/std/src/panicking.rs:552:40
      std::panicking::try
             at rustc/07dca489ac2d933c78d3c5158e3f43beefeb02ce/library/std/src/panicking.rs:516:19
      std::panic::catch_unwind
             at rustc/07dca489ac2d933c78d3c5158e3f43beefeb02ce/library/std/src/panic.rs:142:14
      std::rt::lang_start_internal::{{closure}}
             at rustc/07dca489ac2d933c78d3c5158e3f43beefeb02ce/library/std/src/rt.rs:148:48
      std::panicking::try::do_call
             at rustc/07dca489ac2d933c78d3c5158e3f43beefeb02ce/library/std/src/panicking.rs:552:40
      std::panicking::try
             at rustc/07dca489ac2d933c78d3c5158e3f43beefeb02ce/library/std/src/panicking.rs:516:19
      std::panic::catch_unwind
             at rustc/07dca489ac2d933c78d3c5158e3f43beefeb02ce/library/std/src/panic.rs:142:14
      std::rt::lang_start_internal
             at rustc/07dca489ac2d933c78d3c5158e3f43beefeb02ce/library/std/src/rt.rs:148:20
   9: main
  10: <unknown>
  11: __libc_start_main
  12: _start
             at opt/zig-linux-x86_64-0.11.0/lib/libc/glibc/sysdeps/x86_64/start-2.33.S:120
) } }
stack backtrace:
   0: rust_begin_unwind
             at ./rustc/07dca489ac2d933c78d3c5158e3f43beefeb02ce/library/std/src/panicking.rs:645:5
   1: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at ./rustc/07dca489ac2d933c78d3c5158e3f43beefeb02ce/library/core/src/panicking.rs:72:14
   2: core::result::unwrap_failed
             at ./rustc/07dca489ac2d933c78d3c5158e3f43beefeb02ce/library/core/src/result.rs:1649:5
   3: tskv::kvcore::TsKv::open::{{closure}}
   4: cnosdb::server::ServiceBuilder::create_tskv::{{closure}}
   5: cnosdb::server::ServiceBuilder::build_query_storage::{{closure}}
   6: cnosdb::main::{{closure}}
   7: cnosdb::main
note: Some details are omitted, run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=full` for a verbose backtrace.
[root@localhost ~]#

What problem causes this? Has anyone encountered this before?
